# Permission denied error when starting terminal

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, zsh

I'm getting this error when I start my terminal:

```
/home/USERNAME/.config/envman/PATH.env:2: permission denied: /home/USERNAME/.local/bin
```

this is my .zshrc file:

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh

# Generated for envman. Do not edit.
[ -s "$HOME/.config/envman/load.sh" ] && source "$HOME/.config/envman/load.sh"
source ~/.config/envman/load.sh
eval "$(zoxide init bash)"
```

This is the PATH.env file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
~/.local/bin
```

And these are the permissions for PATH.env:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 USERNAME USERNAME 51 FEB   21 17:02 /home/USERNAME/.config/envman/PATH.en
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the shell script that caused the error (mentioned in the error message) and also what the permissions and ownership are on the path that the error message mentions?

Comment: @Kusalananda Sure, I updated the post with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the error message wrapped to two lines for clarity:

```
/home/USERNAME/.config/envman/PATH.env:2: 
    permission denied: /home/USERNAME/.local/bin
```

It means: "When trying to execute the 2nd line of `PATH.env`, I got the error: `permission denied: /home/USERNAME/.local/bin`.

And the second line of your `PATH.env` is indeed:

```
~/.local/bin
```

Since the previous line is `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`, it seems that `~/.local/bin` is probably a *directory*, and the error is caused by *trying to execute it* as a file.

Comment: Commenting out that line fixed the error for me, I'm wondering what was that line for? how can I know?

Comment: @Ilgar The line is not for anything. It was added to the file in error, probably with `echo '~/.local/bin' >>~/.config/envman/PATH.env` or some similar command, rather than being added to the value of the `PATH` variable in that same file.  As the equivalent path is already properly added to the `PATH` variable, you may remove the line completely from the `PATH.env` file and you don't have to do anything else.  Also, please accept this answer from telcoM if you found that it was helpful.

Comment: I agree with @Kusalananda : the second line should not be there. I've seen errors like that happen when a script that is expecting to process a single line of input from stdin into a file unexpectedly gets two or more lines. If the script is not carefully designed, the extra input may "leak" into the target file without the processing applied to the first line of input.